# Is it normal for printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" to print one line per array element?

Tags: arrays, bash

In my bash script I'm including an array of other files required by the program. I then print those in the help description. When I used printf for their output, I got results I was not expecting. I have read that the form ${array[@]} is generally preferred as the default for expansion, so I started with that.

My array declaration:

```
 scriptDependencies=("script1.sh" "script2.sh")
```

And the (initial) printf command:

```
printf "Dependencies: %s\n" "${scriptDependencies[@]}"
```

What I got as output:

```
 Dependencies: script1.sh
 Dependencies: script2.sh
```

Although I believe I understand a basic difference between the subscripts '@' and '*' to be all individual elements vs all elements grouped together, I was not expecting two separate lines to print.

When I switched the printf command to use the ${scriptDependencies[*]} form, a single line (closer to what I desired) was printed:

```
 Dependencies: script1.sh script2.sh
```

Is this expected behavior of printf, and of the subscripts? Or does it point to a problem with printf?

I'm using GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15).

Comment: If you want to print an array's contents in unambiguous form, consider: `printf 'Dependencies: '; printf '%q ' "${scriptDependencies[@]}"; printf '\n'` -- it's more to write, but it means that `array=( "foo bar" )` and `array=( foo bar )` each have distinct output -- and that `array=( $'foo\nbar' )` will similarly get sane treatment.

Comment: If you don't care as much about formatting control, you can also use `declare -p scriptDependencies`

Comment: Perhaps I should take this to chat? I'm not (so far) able to wrap my little brain around either of your comments, but I've tested both. For the %q format, one of the strings I have in the dependencies array includes " (v2)". When I use %q, the space and the parens have the escape seq added. I don't understand what makes that unambiguous? The declare -p scriptDependencies results in an output of: declare -a scriptDependencies='([0]="script1.sh" [1]="script2.sh")' I get that you mentioned these because there is goodness, but I don't understand. So much to learn, so little time :)

Comment: Re: `%q` -- the output is quoted in such a way that you could copy and paste it back into a shell command line, and it would be interpreted as itself -- that is, all as data, not syntax.

Comment: ...and with respect to `declare -p scriptDependencies`, that gives you a shell command you can run that will *exactly* reproduce the given variable, including aspects of its value that aren't obvious (like the indexes given to values -- arrays in bash can be sparse, which is part of why assigning to an array by index based on the count of items it contains is liable to be buggy).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is documented and expected behavior. If there are more strings passed to `printf` than a format string can handle, that format string will be repeated.

`"${array[@]}"` expands to a shell word per array element. Thus, for an array with two elements, two arguments to `printf` will be passed; if the format string only has one placeholder (only one `%s`), then it will be repeated.

By contrast, `"${array[*]}"` (with the quotes!) will expand to only one argument (with the first character of `IFS`, a space by default, inserted between each element).

---

Bash is required to do this by [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html), emphasis added below:

> 9. **The format operand shall be reused as often as necessary to satisfy the argument operands.** Any extra c or s conversion specifiers shall be evaluated as if a null string argument were supplied; other extra conversion specifications shall be evaluated as if a zero argument were supplied. If the *format* operand contains no conversion specifications and *argument* operands are present, the results are unspecified.

Consequently, this behavior is portable to all POSIX-compliant shells.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected: from `help printf`:

> The format is re-used as necessary to consume all of the arguments.  If
>       there are fewer arguments than the format requires,  extra format
>       specifications behave as if a zero value or null string, as appropriate,
>       had been supplied.

Comment: Very cool. In my system help printf doesn't describe this, but the man page says basically the same thing. But, I'm not sure I would have appreciated what that is saying without having experienced the behavior first hand. Now I'm looking at options to print each dependency on one line without form-feed after the word Dependencies.