# execute bash expression without temporary file in bash native way

Tags: bash, shell

I have worked code

```
id | tr -s ',' '\n' > output1 && tail -n $( expr $(cat output1 | wc -l) - 1 ) output1
```

but i want it without temporary file.
thank you

Comment: What does this code do? What is the goal?

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) issues several warnings for the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to skip the 1st line of output from the `id | tr` command pair:

```
$ id | tr -s ',' '\n' | tail -n +2

# or

$ id | tr -s ',' '\n' | awk 'FNR>1'
```

Or eliminating the `tr` call and printing everything after the 1st `,`:

```
$ id | awk -F, '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $i}'
```

Answer (score 0):

An arguably more "bash native" way to do this is:

```
IFS=, read -r -a id_parts  < <(id)
printf '%s\n' "${id_parts[@]:1}"
```

- See [How to split a string into an array in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10586153/4154375) for an explanation of `IFS=, read -r -a id_parts ...`.
- See [ProcessSubstitution - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) for an explanation of `< <(id)`.
- See [How to slice an array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1335815/4154375) and [Is it normal for printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" to print one line per array element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39690037/4154375) for an explanation of `printf '%s\n' "${id_parts[@]:1}"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get all user-groups and for a better output

```
awk '
   NR==1{split($0,ids); next} 
   {split($0,names)}
   END{
    #for(i in ids) printf "%d(%s)\n", ids[i], names[i]
    for(i in ids) printf "%5d ==> %s\n", ids[i], names[i]
}' <(id -G) <(id -nG)

1000 ==> ufopilot
   4 ==> adm
  27 ==> sudo
 139 ==> docker
```